# Data from request.POST are not being used to fill django form in views

Tags: django

I'm new in a Django and I try to exercise in easy project.

My problem is that when I try to save the data from request.POST to ListForm it doesn't work.
In the  request.POST object  I can find only a `csrf_token`.
Can you help me,how to fix it?

vievs:

```
def home(request):

    if request.method=='POST':
        a=request.POST
        
        form =ListForm(request.POST)

        list_items = List.objects.all
        if form.is_valid():

            form.save()
            list_items=List.objects.all
            #messages.success(request,('Udało się dodać'))
        return render(request,'home.html' ,{'list_items':list_items,'ok':'ok','a':a})
    else:
        list_items = List.objects.all
        return render(request, 'home.html', {'list_items': list_items,'nie_ok':'nie_ok'})
```

form in html:

```
<form class="d-flex" action="{% url 'home' %}" method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" id='teraz'placeholder="your new task" aria-label="Search">
        <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary"  name="item">Add to list</button>
      </form>
```

`request.POST` object:

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['jCBOIk4mLr96d6ffPUDiLdJ01oVsw5eAATzeJqlQrC0H4TYTAP8OqnQFHrFZgOeo'], 'item': ['']}>
```

models:

```
class List(models.Model):
    item=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    completed=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.item
```

forms:

```
class ListForm (forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model =List
        fields=['item','completed']
```

Comment: The input must have then `name` attribute: `name="item"`

Comment: I suggest you to add `ListForm` in context. See [Building a form in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#the-template)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your html, you need add attribute `name` for input:

```
<input name="item" class="form-control me-2" type="search" ...>
```

A quick way when your form have more fields, you can declare form in `views.py`:

```
def home(request):
    list_form = ListForm()

    context = {
        'list_form': list_form,
        'list_items': list_items,
        # ...
    }
    return render(request, 'home.html', context=context)
```

And use `django form` in your template, Django will auto generate for you all input fields.

```
<form method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ list_form.as_p }}
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

By the way, if you have attribute name for button in your form:

```
<input type="button" name="btn-a" value="A">
<input type="button" name="btn-b" value="B">
```

You can check user click `btn-a` or `btn-b`:

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       if 'btn-a' in request.POST:
           # do something when user click button A
       if 'btn-b' in request.POST:
           # do something when user click button B
    # ...
```